# How can I prevent integers being silently turned to asterisks in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have a table account, there is one field `acct_type varchar(2)`

```
Insert into account(acct_type) values(888)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
| acct_type |
+-----------+
| *         |
+-----------+
```

I'm expecting it will throw an error when insert statement trigger.
Why it's storing `*` value in table?

Comment: @SMor: or maybe the table is defined incorrectly. If the application wants to store numbers (integers) in there, maybe the column should be defined as `integer` rather than `varchar`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `varchar` datatype a truncated `int` will be cast as `*` instead of throwing an error (in this case as the three digits don't fit in a `varchar(2)`).

This does not happen with `nvarchar`

There is no way of changing this behaviour, it is preserved for backwards compatibility. If this is a real problem for you you can add a check constraint that the value in the column is not `*` but I can't imagine any situation where this is really worth doing.

The solution is just not to do that. If you must insert an `INT` then validate it is in the range `-9 to 99` first. Or always use quotes around values destined for a string column rather than relying on implicit conversions.

Comment: Thanks Martin!..How can i put a check constraint to prevent integer value in varchar filed...can you please help me to write syntax?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE account ADD CONSTRAINT CK_NoStar_acct_type CHECK (acct_type <> '*')` but you almost certainly don't need to do this. There are a ton of `char/varchar` columns in the wild with length of `10` or less where this is a theoretical possibility that get on just fine without that. The check constraint will of course also block an explicit insert of `*` as it has no way of distinguishing between how the `*` was arrived at

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin!! now i can properly explain to my developer with syntax and side efects of this

Comment: I think the real question is: if they want to store integer values, then why is this a `varchar` to begin with?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you have a question for the OP put it on the question not an answer. They won't get notified here. I would say there is nothing in the question that indicates that they only ever intend to store integers in this column though "888" is not a valid value for the `varchar(2)` anyway. All that can be inferred is that they attempted it at least once and got an unexpected result that they would rather have errored than fail silently.